# Dir does not working with Excel 2016 to list csv files

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to use the dir function with Excel 2016, but it does not work :

```
fPath = "C:\csv"
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
fCSV = Dir(fPath & "*.csv")

    Do While Len(fCSV) > 0
        Set wbCSV = Workbooks.Open(fPath & fCSV)
        ActiveSheet.Move After:=wbMST.Sheets(wbMST.Sheets.Count)

        fCSV = Dir
    Loop

Set wbCSV = Nothing
```

I stored into `c:\csv` several csv files.

`fCSV` is always equal to `''`

any idea ?

Comment: Change to `"C:\csv\"` else your wildcarded path is not valid.

Comment: Great, thanks, it's working